# I want to export oracle table into an Excel sheet side by side

Tags: excel, linux, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, spool

I have few oracle tables and I want to fix them into a same excel sheet side by side using spool command.

Can I use cell reference inside spool command while trying to export those tables into a excel file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Spool writes plain text

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlplus user/pass@db

SQL>set markup csv on quote off;
SQL>spool output.csv
SQL>SELECT * FROM table;
.......
SQL>spool off
SQL>exit
```

Now open in Excel, and it should prompt you to convert what it sees as a text file. Tell it to use commas as the field delimiters, and it will import into a spreadsheet. Or open in a text editor and change commas to tabs, and then you can even copy/paste the contents directly into Excel and it will paste correctly into the rows/columns automatically.

If you have commas in your data, you can change the delimiter to another character that you don't have:

```
set markup csv on delimiter | quote off;
```

Or even more easy than that, simply query the table in the database client software of your choice, configured to copy with tab delimiters (if it gives you this option). Using DBArtisan, I simply highlight my results, `ctrl-c`, and `ctrl-v` into Excel and it works perfectly. No need to go through SQL*Plus and spool to file. I imagine other popular clients can do the same.

It is possible to create an Excel XML document using PL/SQL which you can email to yourself, but that's a lot more complicated than the above.

Answer (score 0):

[You tagged sql developer, you can use the cart to export your tables to  single Excel file, each table will get it's own Worksheet](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2018/01/exporting-multiple-tables-to-a-single-excel-file-using-sql-developers-cart/)

[image]

Set output options, and voila

[image]